# AlertDialog Displays Landscape-Sized View with Orientation in Landscape

Tags: android, orientation, android-alertdialog, landscape-portrait

My app's main activity is set in the manifest to always be in portrait view.  This works fine when I load the app onto the tablet.

However, when I use my menu button and click "Setup", which opens an `AlertDialog` that inflates an xml layout, the tablet will display the left 2/3 or so of the entire dialog.  The rest of it goes offscreen to the right.  This case only occurs if I install my app on the tablet while holding it in landscape mode or if I turn the tablet to landscape mode while the app is not running (even if I go back to Portrait and click on the app).  The dialog even calls `this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` to make sure it stays in portrait (even though the problem persists with this call or not).

In other words, the way the `AlertDialog` is being displayed in portrait view is that it is blowing up a landscape view (and thus some of it goes offscreen), even though the actual orientation of the `AlertDialog` is portrait, like it should be.

(I apologize if the wording above was confusing - ask me to clarify anything if needed.)

So why would the tablet do this?  I've tested it on a few android mobile phones and this doesn't happen, so I don't understand why the tablet will do this.

**SIDE NOTES:**

- This isn't even occurring for just this `AlertDialog` either.. my EULA that displays at the start of the app (another `AlertDialog`) also appears this way if I start the app in landscape mode.
- I've even allowed the usability of landscape by getting rid of all calls to specify portrait/landscape mode, and the tablet is still expending the dialog off-screen when held in portrait view on just the tablet, but not the phones.

**EDIT:**

This code works well on the phone, but the tablet problem still persists.  If I uncomment `dialog.show();` below, the tablet and phone display the dimensions I want, but on blackness instead of the dimmed main screen.  Any ideas?

Calling function does this:

```
showDialog(EXAMPLE_CASE);
```

Function that gets called by the calling function:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(final int id) {
        Dialog dialog;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
        int mwidth = display.getWidth();
        int mheight = display.getHeight();

        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

        switch(id) {
        // Example of what all my cases look like (there were way too many to copy)
        case EXAMPLE_CASE:

            builder.setTitle("Example")
            .setMessage("Example message")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface,int i) {
                    dialoginterface.dismiss();
                    showDialog(DIALOG_CHOICE);
                }
            })
           .setCancelable(false);

            dialog = builder.create();

            break;
        }


        if (dialog != null) {

            lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
            lp.width = mwidth;
            lp.height = mheight;
            lp.x = mwidth;
            //lp.y = mheight;
            lp.dimAmount=0.0f;
            //dialog.show();
            dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
            dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

            dialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    removeDialog(id);
                }
            });
        }

    return dialog;
}
```

Comment: Did you any other solution than answered below

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try getting the screen dimensions like this:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int mwidth = display.getWidth();
int mheight = display.getHeight();
```

And then alter the `Dialog` like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
Dialog d = adb.setView(new View(this)).create();
// (That new View is just there to have something inside the dialog that can grow big enough to cover the whole screen.)

d.show();

WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
lp.copyFrom(d.getWindow().getAttributes());
lp.width = mwidth;
lp.height = myheight;

//change position of window on screen
lp.x = mwidth/2; //set these values to what work for you; probably like I have here at
lp.y = mheight/2;        //half the screen width and height so it is in center

//set the dim level of the background
lp.dimAmount=0.1f; //change this value for more or less dimming

d.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

//add a blur/dim flags
d.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

Also, you say you are inflating a custom layout. Have you tried tinkering with the `layout_height` and `layout_width` of the views in that layout to see if that makes a difference?