# Android Alert Dialog change width

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an alert dialog (image and text in each row), but it is too wide. How can I change the width of the dialog?

My code:

```
    ListAdapter adapter = new AnimalAdapter(this, _options );

    final AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    ad.setTitle("Options");
    ad.setSingleChoiceItems( adapter, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String selectedVal = _options[which].getVal();
            options_selected_item = selectedVal;
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    ad.show();
```

I have tried adding `ad.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400);` before and after `ad.show();` but I get

```
The method getWindow() is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder.
```

Comment: Nothing. The dialog doesn't appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431041/alertdialog-displays-landscape-sized-view-with-orientation-in-landscape/9436029#9436029) at some of the solutions that I suggested. I give a code example and try to explain how it works.

Comment: Please include more than just a link in this answer. As it is, it doesn't provide mucha nd may be deleted if not edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the dialog before showing it:

```
Dialog dialog = ad.create();
dialog.show();
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400);
```